# Is this partial derivative well calculated?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

The question (from Fleming's book on several variables function) is the following. Let $f$ be a $C^2$ function, and set $F(x,y)=f(x,xy)$. Find the mixed partial derivative $F_{12}$.

First, I calculate $$F_1(x,y)=f_1(x,xy)+yf_2(x,xy)$$ And then
$$
F_{12}(x,y)=xf_{12}(x,xy)+f_2(x,xy)+xyf_{22}(x,xy)
$$
Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that's fine.